# Jquery on click of li tag ID show reliative Div which has ID

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. On click of li tag which has an ID I need to show the relative div which has an ID. For e.g. on click of anchor tag ID note_1, I need to show of content of div ID notContent_1.

Following is my code.

```
 <ul>
    <li id="note_1">1</li>
    <li id="note_2">2</li>
    <li id="note_3">3</li>
    <li id="note_4">4</li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div id="notContent_1">A</div>
    <div id="notContent_2">B</div>
    <div id="notContent_3">C</div>
    <div id="notContent_4">d</div>
</div>
```

On click of each li tag I need to show relative ID's div. I don't want to write a method for each li tag.

Comment: first try to do it yourself please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this for example :

```
$('li[id^="note_"]').click(function(){
    $('[id^="notContent_"]').hide(); // hide the other divs
    $('#notContent_'+this.id.slice(5)).show();
});
```

This uses the ["attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    $('div#notContent_' + $(this).text()).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzE6T/1/)

**Edit** just saw, this is considering that your list text is actually 1-4

If the text is not 1-4, you could add class to the div containing the elemens and use index and eq() like this

```
$('.tab-content div:eq('+$(this).index()+')').show().siblings().hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzE6T/2/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I need to show only one div's content on a time

Comment: Add `.siblings().hide();` after `.show()` it will hide all the other siblings

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //detecting and handling click on list element
    $('li').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //get the number from list item's id using regex
        var number = id.match(/\d/g);

        //showing div with id notContent_+number
        $('#notContent_'+number).show();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with this: [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
    $('ul > li').on('click', function () {
        $('div#notContent_' + $(this).text()).show();
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vszG9/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple links, there is a pure html solution :

```
<ul id="links">
    <li id="note_1"><a href="#notContent_1">1</a></li>
    <li id="note_2"><a href="#notContent_2">2</a></li>
    <li id="note_3"><a href="#notContent_3">3</a></li>
    <li id="note_4"><a href="#notContent_4">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="notContent">
    <div id="notContent_1">A</div>
    <div id="notContent_2">B</div>
    <div id="notContent_3">C</div>
    <div id="notContent_4">d</div>
</div>
```

If you want to hide the other divs and show the "selected" one, you can add some javascript :

```
$('#links').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#notContent div').hide();
  $( $(this).attr('href') ).show();
});
```

If you want to have tabs or accodions, use an appropriate library (e.g. [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), ... )